# Convert BigInteger Decimal to Binary back with all leading zero

Tags: c#, biginteger

I have the code below to convert String ex. "0000010100000101" to Decimal Number of type BigInteger. Now I want to convert the decimal number back to binary, the result should be same as the first String with all the leading zeros. I wish you can use the same method of converting from binary to decimal because it's super fast, because the binary I will really use is really big same to the decimal.

Binary string could be anything and should go back to the same as it was.

```
BigInteger Decimalvalue = 0;  
string binaryAsString = "0000010100000101";

int numOfBytes = binaryAsString.Length / 8;
if ((binaryAsString.Length % 8) != 0)
numOfBytes++;
byte[] bytes = new byte[numOfBytes];
for (int i = 1; i <= numOfBytes; ++i)
{
    int start = binaryAsString.Length - i * 8;
    int length = 8;
    if (start < 0)
    {
        length += start;
        start = 0;
    }
    bytes[numOfBytes - i] = Convert.ToByte(binaryAsString.Substring(start, length), 2);
}

Decimalvalue = new BigInteger(bytes.Concat(new byte[] { 0 }).ToArray());

Console.WriteLine("Decimal value = ");
Console.WriteLine(Decimalvalue);
```

I expect the converting from Decimalvalue will return the original binary string "0000010100000101".

Comment: Is there a reason why you expect it to return the same number of bits? In a big endian system, `0000010100000101` and `10100000101` are both the same value. If you need a specific number of bits, why not pad with zeroes?

Comment: Keep/store the length of the original string. Then, after converting the number back to a binary string, left-pad the resulting string with an appropriate amount of `'0'` characters (based on the length of the original string you have stored in some field/property/whatever somewhere...). The String class has suitable methods to realize this kind of padding...